# What is the fastest way to load file using python and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, io, bigdata

I want to train a model and I have a big dataset for training.
Its size is more than 20gb.
But when I try to read it, it took so long time.
I mean to load it on memory.

```
with open(file_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i,row in enumerate(islice(reader,0,1)):
        train_data = np.array(makefloat(row))[None,:]
    for i,row in enumerate(reader):
        train_data = np.vstack((train_data,np.array(makefloat(row))[None,:]))
```

It has 43 floats for each line.

It took so long time, I tested it for just 100,000 lines and it took 20 mins.

I think I'm doing wrong. How can I make it faster?

Comment: You probably don't want to read the whole file into memory. Try to load batches of data. If you are using Tensorflow or Keras to train, you can probably setup a proper data pipeline that will handle it for you.

Comment: Repeated `vstack` like that is slow.  Better to collect rows in a list, and do one `vstack` at the end.

Comment: The pandas csv reader is faster than numpy ones (`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`).

Answer (score 0):

Its' not good to read the entire file. You can use something like Dask which will read your file in chunks and will be faster.
[Dask](https://github.com/dask/dask)